# X3D ImageTexture without URLs

Tags: java, x3d

I'm making a project in `Java` that loads `X3D` files and it works great with `X3D` files that don't contain a URL. But the `X3D` files that I need to use have URLs contained within them. I'm wondering if there's a way that I can use a `JPEG` within an `X3D` file without using `imageTexture url='"http//:website.com/album/photo.jpg"'`. So I was wondering if I could save the `JPEG` on my laptop and then put it into the `X3D` file that way? Or is there another way about doing this?

Comment: Replacing the URL `"http//:website.com/album/photo.jpg"` with `"photo.jpg"` and putting the `photo.jpg` file into the same folder as the X3D does not work? (And @ the downvoter: What's so wrong about this question?)

Comment: @Marco13 Replacing `"http//:website.com/album/photo.jpg"` with `photo.jpg` and putting `photo.jpg` in the same folder as the X3D file doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with X3D, this was just a guess. (And I assume that there are no helpful error messages...?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a reference to the image file inside the X3D file. The reference can be any URI (**URL** or **local path**). The correct way of loading an image is by using the **ImageTexture** element. The other two elements that are able to load an image in an X3D file is **VideoTexture** and **Inline** but I would suggest to use ImageTexture. As Marco13 guessed, if you want to use a local image, instead of providing the URL to the image which is stored somewhere on internet you have to provide the local path to the locally stored image file, e.g. ImageTexture { url ["path/to/image.jpeg"] }